# What is an "Options Framework" for Wordpress

Tags: wp-admin, options, framework

I am exploring a couple options frameworks for wordpress like the Redux Framework. As a non-developer interested in maintaining my own Wordpress based web app, when would an options framework like Redux be useful?

Most sites for options framework market their tool to the wordpress developer community. I have not found a simple explanation geared toward non-developers or newbies that clarifies when an options framework should be used.

http://reduxframework.com/

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An options framework is designed to make the creation of settings pages for plugins and themes easier.

An options (or settings) page is a page in the WordPress Dashboard where the behavior of the theme or plugin can be controlled.

For example, themes will often have a settings page to setup color schemes, logos, and other similar options.

WordPress core (the main base software) has a system for setting up option pages, but it is a bit clunky and can be difficult for developers to get the hang of.

Option frameworks, such as Redux, aid developers in the creation of their settings pages by making it much simpler to setup the settings.